# Upload files from one domain on another domain

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions, cross-domain, file-permissions

I need that when a user uploads a file then the file gets stored on a folder on an another domain.
I need to upload files from one domain on another domain. From www.uploadto.com/ to www.uploadedfiles.com/uploadedfiles
I have a simple php website .
The user uploads files and images using that website . 
But at the back-end I need to store the images in a folder on some other domain which is on the same server.
How do I do it? Please help.
I  have my website hosted on Linux Apache server .
I have given the whole path including the username in the move_uploaded_file parameters. But am getting permissions error?

Comment: @Mike `which is on the same server` - easiest way is `copy()`/`rename()`, or just put the files in the right place on the **local** file system in the first place. FTPing stuff to yourself adds huge amounts of pointless overhead. Permissions just need to be set right.

Comment: @Mike I need that when a user uploads a file then the file gets stored on a folder on an another domain.

Comment: @sqlchild `another domain` is actually just `another directory` if the domains are hosted on the same server. You just need to know the local file system path of the other domain's home directory.

Comment: @DaveRandom : am not sure about the same server. what if the other hosting domain is hosted on different server.

Comment: If it's on another server, you will have to transfer it with some network protocol, e.g. you could HTTP POST it there (using e.g. [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)) or as @Mike suggested, via FTP.

Comment: @DaveRandom : In the case of same server, what permissions shall I put on the folder in which the files are to be stored.....7 0 0  OR  7 5 5 or ????????????

Comment: Thanks @DaveRandom how did i miss that theyre on same server. In which case Dave is correct its a permissions issue. chmod to 755 or 777 i'd guess or chown them as the same user.

Comment: @DaveRandom : sir, the folder permissions get automatically changed to 750 ? i had set it to 755 but it gets changed itself. This problem occurred after the cross domain uploading..

Comment: Sounds like the host is implementing chroot etc in order to prevent cross-domain activity, if you contact you host they can probably remove this restriction for the two domains in question.

Comment: if i put permissions to 755 it says creating directory fails ? what code should i write? how to chmod?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery uploadify to upload the file to the image server,then get the url to another server.